# Files with mixed encoding - Python

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, file-encodings

I have some files with mixed encodings, I believe UTF-8 and UTF-16LE. It's a mix of some English letters but mostly Chinese characters. Goal: use Python to convert the file all to UTF-8. '\n' ought to be a newline.

The answer to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10009753/python-dealing-with-mixed-encoding-files) seemed like it would help. Unfortunately, (I believe) because UTF-16 is not a variable-length encoding, when I try to decode the file first using UTF-8 but falling back on UTF-16, I get this error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf16' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: truncated data.

File data is below. I've played around with it for a while and can't seem to get anything to work. There is plenty that I'm not sure about as well; I know that the beginning of the file has a BOM, but I don't understand the rest of the encoding issues very well. Thanks for your help!

print %r, using the open function:

```
'\xff\xfe"\x00W\x00a\x00n\x00t\x00e\x00d\x00C\x00r\x00o\x00p\x00p\x00e\x00d\x00/\x001\x003\x00.\x00j\x00p\x00g\x00"\x00\t\x00"\x00 \x00\\\x00n\x00\\\x00n\x00\\\x00u\x008\x006\x001\x001\x00,\x00-\x00\'\x00\\\x00u\x006\x00b\x006\x004\x00\\\x00u\x005\x006\x00d\x00b\x00\\\x00u\x009\x000\x00e\x001\x00\\\x00u\x005\x004\x00b\x008\x00\\\x00u\x007\x000\x000\x009\x00]\x00 \x00\\\x00u\x009\x000\x00e\x001\x00\\\x00u\x003\x000\x001\x00d\x00\\\x00"\x00\\\x00u\x005\x004\x000\x00c\x00\\\x00u\x006\x00a\x003\x009\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x004\x00b\x00\\\x00u\x005\x004\x001\x00f\x00[\x00\\\x00u\x003\x000\x000\x00f\x00\\\x00u\x008\x00d\x006\x006\x00\\\x00u\x003\x000\x001\x00d\x00\\\x00u\x009\x000\x002\x003\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x00d\x009\x00\\\x00u\x003\x000\x001\x00d\x00\\\x00u\x005\x009\x008\x002\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x009\x004\x00\\\x00u\x005\x00d\x00b\x00d\x00\\\x00u\x003\x000\x001\x00d\x00Z\x00\\\x00u\x008\x007\x00f\x002\x00\\\x00n\x00\\\x00u\x007\x00e\x003\x00d\x00\\\x00u\x008\x00f\x001\x00d\x00\\\x00u\x002\x000\x002\x006\x00\\\x00u\x005\x007\x00c\x003\x00 \x00\\\x00u\x005\x004\x00e\x00a\x00\\\x00u\x006\x00c\x009\x00b\x00\\\x00u\x005\x007\x000\x00b\x00\\\x00u\x006\x00a\x003\x009\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x005\x00f\x00-\x00 \x00\\\x00u\x005\x00c\x007\x001\x00\\\x00u\x005\x005\x00d\x00a\x00\\\x00u\x003\x000\x001\x005\x00\\\x00u\x005\x000\x001\x001\x00\\\x00u\x007\x00f\x00a\x009\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x001\x008\x00\\\x00u\x008\x007\x003\x004\x00\\\x00u\x003\x000\x001\x00d\x00\\\x00u\x007\x00d\x002\x00b\x00\\\x00u\x009\x006\x007\x00d\x00\\\x00u\x009\x00c\x00f\x003\x00\\\x00u\x009\x006\x007\x00d\x00\\\x00u\x007\x006\x00c\x00e\x00\\\x00n\x00\\\x00u\x006\x007\x009\x00d\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x005\x00f\x00\'\x00 \x00\\\x00u\x008\x008\x006\x001\x00\\\x00u\x005\x00c\x007\x001\x00\\\x00u\x006\x00c\x00f\x000\x00\\\x00u\x005\x00c\x007\x001\x00\\\x00u\x005\x00c\x00b\x001\x00\\\x00u\x005\x00c\x007\x001\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x005\x00f\x00o\x00\\\x00u\x005\x009\x00d\x004\x00\\\x00u\x007\x00b\x00e\x004\x00\\\x00u\x007\x003\x00c\x00a\x00\\\x00u\x007\x006\x007\x00d\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00f\x00d\x007\x00\\\x00u\x005\x006\x00e\x000\x00\\\x00u\x002\x000\x003\x005\x00 \x00\\\x00u\x006\x007\x002\x00c\x00\\\x00u\x008\x00e\x002\x00b\x00\\\x00u\x009\x008\x000\x006\x00!\x00\\\x00u\x003\x000\x001\x00d\x00\\\x00n\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x000\x000\x00\\\x00u\x006\x002\x00b\x005\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x00e\x005\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x000\x000\x00 \x00\\\x00u\x009\x000\x00e\x001\x00\\\x00u\x005\x004\x000\x00d\x00\\\x00u\x008\x000\x000\x00c\x00\\\x00u\x005\x00c\x000\x00a\x00\\\x00u\x003\x000\x000\x00f\x00\\\x00u\x005\x001\x00a\x000\x00\\\x00u\x003\x000\x001\x005\x00\\\x00u\x00f\x00f\x000\x00c\x00\\\x00u\x003\x000\x001\x00d\x00 \x00\\\x00u\x005\x009\x002\x00b\x00[\x00\\\x00u\x008\x00f\x00e\x005\x00\\\x00u\x005\x003\x00c\x00a\x00\\\x00u\x007\x008\x003\x007\x00\\\x00u\x006\x00d\x003\x002\x00\\\x00u\x005\x004\x00a\x00f\x00l\x00\\\x00u\x008\x006\x005\x005\x00\\\x00u\x005\x00b\x002\x004\x00\\\x00u\x005\x005\x00b\x005\x00I\x00\\\x00u\x005\x009\x004\x00f\x00\\\x00n\x00\\\x00u\x008\x008\x00d\x004\x00\\\x00u\x005\x000\x001\x001\x00\\\x00u\x005\x00f\x007\x00c\x00\\\x00u\x006\x00b\x006\x004\x00\\\x00u\x008\x005\x006\x00a\x00\\\x00u\x006\x00c\x006\x00a\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x000\x000\x00\\\x00u\x009\x006\x008\x003\x00o\x004\x00[\x00\\\x00u\x005\x009\x00d\x001\x00\\\x00u\x008\x000\x005\x006\x00\\\x00u\x005\x003\x00e\x00d\x00}\x00]\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x009\x004\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x00f\x000\x00\\\x00u\x006\x000\x009\x004\x00\\\x00u\x008\x000\x001\x000\x00\\\x00u\x005\x00b\x005\x008\x00\\\x00u\x008\x007\x001\x008\x00\\\x00u\x005\x00d\x00f\x002\x00\\\x00u\x005\x004\x001\x000\x00\\\x00u\x007\x004\x002\x00a\x00\\\x00u\x003\x000\x001\x00d\x00 \x00\\\x00u\x008\x00c\x00b\x004\x00\\\x00n\x00\\\x00u\x005\x009\x002\x009\x00\\\x00u\x006\x00d\x00a\x00f\x00\\\x00u\x008\x002\x00e\x005\x00\\\x00u\x005\x003\x001\x007\x00\\\x00u\x009\x001\x003\x000\x00 \x00\\\x00u\x003\x000\x001\x00d\x00\\\x00u\x002\x000\x003\x002\x00 \x00\\\x00u\x008\x000\x006\x00f\x00\\\x00u\x007\x006\x00e\x007\x00\\\x00u\x005\x004\x002\x005\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x00e\x005\x00\\\x00u\x003\x000\x000\x00e\x00\\\x00u\x005\x003\x004\x003\x00\\\x00u\x008\x00f\x000\x009\x00\\\x00u\x009\x001\x00c\x00d\x00\\\x00u\x006\x00b\x006\x001\x00\\\x00u\x005\x003\x00d\x006\x00\\\x00u\x007\x008\x007\x00c\x00\\\x00u\x003\x000\x000\x00d\x00\\\x00u\x005\x00b\x00e\x00b\x00\\\x00u\x005\x001\x00f\x00a\x00\\\x00u\x005\x00b\x005\x000\x00\\\x00u\x003\x000\x001\x00d\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x00c\x003\x00 \x00\\\x00u\x003\x000\x000\x00e\x00\\\x00n\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x004\x00b\x00\\\x00u\x009\x009\x009\x006\x00)\x00 \x00\\\x00u\x008\x002\x00f\x004\x00\\\x00u\x003\x000\x000\x008\x00\\\x00u\x005\x007\x009\x00a\x00\\\x00u\x006\x000\x001\x00d\x00\\\x00u\x006\x005\x00b\x00c\x00\\\x00u\x006\x00b\x006\x004\x00\\\x00u\x008\x000\x003\x003\x00@\x00\\\x00n\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x00c\x001\x00 \x00\\\x00u\x005\x003\x004\x001\x00]\x00 \x00\\\x00u\x006\x007\x002\x00c\x00\\\x00u\x008\x00e\x002\x00b\x00\\\x00u\x005\x00c\x00a\x00b\x00\\\x00u\x007\x00f\x00a\x004\x00\\\x00u\x005\x00c\x004\x001\x00\\\x00u\x003\x000\x000\x008\x00\\\x00u\x005\x00c\x007\x00e\x00}\x00\\\x00u\x005\x004\x007\x001\x00\\\x00u\x003\x000\x000\x00f\x00\\\x00u\x005\x002\x009\x00b\x00\\\x00u\x002\x000\x003\x005\x00 \x00\\\x00u\x005\x006\x00b\x004\x00\\\x00u\x003\x000\x001\x00d\x00\'\x00\\\x00u\x008\x000\x008\x00b\x00\\\x00u\x009\x00e\x00b\x00b\x00\\\x00u\x005\x003\x00e\x00d\x00\\\x00u\x005\x002\x00d\x008\x00\\\x00u\x005\x00c\x007\x00e\x00l\x00\\\x00u\x006\x005\x002\x00f\x00\\\x00u\x006\x00d\x004\x001\x00\\\x00u\x005\x005\x008\x009\x00\\\x00u\x005\x00d\x00f\x00e\x00\\\x00u\x006\x00e\x000\x005\x00_\x00I\x00\\\x00u\x005\x00f\x00d\x006\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x001\x006\x00\\\x00u\x009\x00f\x003\x00b\x00\\\x00n\x00{\x00 \x00\\\x00u\x006\x00b\x002\x001\x00\\\x00u\x006\x001\x00f\x008\x00\\\x00u\x006\x00b\x008\x00a\x00\\\x00u\x009\x008\x006\x00f\x00\\\x00u\x008\x009\x008\x00b\x00\\\x00u\x008\x002\x000\x00a\x00\\\x00u\x006\x007\x002\x00c\x00\\\x00u\x006\x007\x000\x009\x00\\\x00u\x006\x00b\x005\x00f\x00.\x00 \x00\\\x00u\x005\x00f\x008\x001\x00\\\x00u\x005\x00c\x007\x00e\x00\\\x00u\x009\x00b\x00a\x00a\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x00e\x005\x00\\\x00u\x006\x006\x00f\x004\x00)\x00 \x00\\\x00u\x004\x00f\x008\x00b\x00\\\x00u\x005\x009\x008\x002\x00\'\x00\\\x00u\x006\x002\x006\x003\x00_\x00\\\x00u\x003\x000\x000\x00e\x00l\x00\\\x00u\x005\x00c\x007\x00e\x00\\\x00n\x00\\\x00u\x008\x003\x007\x003\x00\\\x00u\x006\x005\x009\x007\x00!\x00\\\x00u\x009\x005\x00a\x009\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x004\x00b\x00\\\x00u\x009\x001\x00d\x001\x00\\\x00u\x009\x001\x00f\x005\x00\\\x00u\x006\x00e\x00a\x00a\x00\\\x00u\x008\x00e\x002\x00b\x00\\\x00u\x005\x005\x008\x00e\x00\\\x00u\x003\x000\x000\x001\x00 \x00\\\x00u\x006\x001\x004\x004\x00\\\x00u\x006\x00c\x009\x00b\x00\\\x00u\x005\x007\x000\x00b\x00 \x00\\\x00u\x009\x000\x00e\x001\x00\\\x00u\x006\x005\x008\x007\x00\\\x00u\x008\x009\x003\x006\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x001\x005\x00\\\x00u\x003\x000\x001\x00e\x00\\\x00u\x005\x000\x002\x003\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x000\x00b\x00\\\x00u\x005\x003\x004\x001\x00 \x00\\\x00u\x005\x00c\x007\x00e\x00\\\x00n\x00\\\x00n\x00 \x00\\\x00n\x00\\\x00n\x00 \x00\\\x00n\x00\\\x00n\x00 \x00\\\x00n\x00\\\x00n\x00 \x00\\\x00u\x003\x000\x001\x001\x00 \x00 \x00\\\x00u\x003\x000\x001\x000\x00I\x00\\\x00u\x000\x002\x00c\x00b\x00 \x00\\\x00u\x003\x000\x001\x000\x00\\\x00u\x003\x000\x001\x001\x00\\\x00u\x008\x005\x001\x004\x00l\x00I\x00_\x00I\x00(\x00\\\x00u\x002\x000\x003\x005\x00\\\x00u\x002\x000\x003\x002\x00l\x00|\x00\\\x00u\x005\x00f\x00d\x006\x00|\x00\\\x00u\x009\x004\x008\x000\x00|\x00\\\x00u\x000\x002\x00c\x00b\x00|\x00 \x00\\\x00u\x000\x002\x00c\x00b\x00 \x00\\\x00u\x000\x002\x00c\x00b\x00 \x00\\\x00u\x003\x000\x000\x009\x00_\x00\\\x00u\x003\x000\x001\x001\x00I\x00L\x00 \x00\\\x00u\x003\x000\x001\x00d\x00l\x00\\\x00n\x00\\\x00n\x00 \x00 \x00 \x00\\\x00n\x00\\\x00n\x00\\\x00u\x003\x000\x001\x00d\x00 \x00\\\x00u\x005\x004\x00b\x00d\x00,\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x001\x006\x00\\\x00u\x006\x003\x00c\x000\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00f\x008\x00d\x00\\\x00u\x007\x006\x00b\x00f\x00^\x00\\\x00u\x005\x002\x00a\x000\x00\\\x00u\x003\x000\x001\x00e\x00\\\x00u\x005\x002\x007\x004\x00]\x00\\\x00u\x009\x005\x007\x007\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x008\x008\x00\\\x00u\x006\x006\x00f\x000\x00\\\x00u\x005\x009\x002\x002\x00\\\x00u\x009\x001\x00d\x001\x00\\\x00u\x006\x001\x00f\x007\x00 \x00\\\x00u\x007\x007\x003\x008\x00\\\x00u\x005\x004\x00e\x00a\x00\\\x00u\x002\x000\x003\x002\x00\\\x00u\x005\x003\x005\x00a\x00\\\x00u\x006\x001\x007\x006\x00)\x00 \x00.\x00\\\x00u\x008\x00a\x005\x00b\x00\\\x00u\x005\x00c\x007\x00e\x00\'\x00\\\x00u\x006\x002\x000\x00c\x00\\\x00u\x002\x000\x002\x006\x00\\\x00n\x00\\\x00u\x006\x007\x005\x000\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x001\x005\x00\\\x00u\x006\x00d\x003\x00e\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x000\x00b\x00\\\x00u\x005\x003\x004\x001\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x001\x006\x00\\\x00u\x005\x00b\x006\x00b\x00\\\x00u\x005\x001\x004\x001\x00\\\x00u\x007\x007\x00f\x003\x00\\\x00u\x005\x002\x000\x000\x00\\\x00u\x003\x000\x000\x00f\x00\\\x00u\x006\x001\x00e\x006\x00\\\x00u\x005\x00b\x00e\x00b\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x008\x008\x00\\\x00u\x003\x000\x000\x001\x00 \x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x008\x008\x00_\x00.\x00\\\x00u\x008\x00d\x00b\x004\x00\\\x00u\x006\x006\x00f\x004\x00\\\x00n\x00\\\x00u\x006\x00b\x006\x003\x00o\x00\\\x00n\x00\\\x00n\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x000\x000\x00\\\x00u\x003\x000\x001\x001\x00 \x00\\\x00u\x008\x004\x00b\x00c\x00\\\x00u\x007\x005\x002\x00b\x00\\\x00u\x006\x007\x003\x001\x00\\\x00u\x008\x006\x005\x005\x00\\\x00u\x006\x00d\x003\x00e\x00\\\x00u\x002\x000\x003\x005\x00 \x00\\\x00u\x004\x00f\x00c\x002\x00\\\x00u\x005\x003\x00c\x00b\x00\\\x00u\x005\x00c\x007\x00e\x00\\\x00u\x009\x007\x008\x008\x00\\\x00u\x005\x00f\x00e\x00a\x00\\\x00u\x006\x00d\x003\x00e\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x000\x00b\x00\\\x00u\x005\x00e\x00f\x00f\x00\\\x00u\x005\x006\x00d\x00b\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x001\x006\x00\\\x00u\x005\x00b\x006\x00b\x00\\\x00u\x005\x001\x006\x00c\x00\\\x00u\x005\x003\x00c\x00b\x00\\\x00n\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x001\x005\x00\\\x00u\x005\x009\x00c\x00b\x00\\\x00u\x009\x000\x007\x007\x00)\x00 \x00\\\x00u\x005\x001\x007\x006\x00\\\x00u\x007\x006\x004\x006\x00\\\x00u\x007\x007\x00b\x003\x00\\\x00u\x009\x001\x002\x002\x00\\\x00u\x005\x00e\x00b\x008\x00{\x00\\\x00u\x007\x002\x003\x006\x00)\x00 \x00\\\x00u\x007\x00a\x00c\x00b\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x00e\x005\x00\\\x00u\x002\x000\x003\x002\x00\\\x00u\x005\x001\x006\x00c\x00\\\x00u\x005\x003\x00c\x00b\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x000\x000\x00\\\x00u\x005\x001\x006\x00c\x00\\\x00n\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x000\x00b\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x009\x004\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x001\x006\x00\\\x00u\x008\x004\x00c\x000\x00\\\x00u\x002\x000\x003\x005\x00 \x00\\\x00u\x005\x007\x004\x007\x00\\\x00u\x006\x00c\x004\x002\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x001\x005\x00\\\x00u\x007\x000\x000\x009\x00\\\x00u\x008\x000\x008\x007\x00\\\x00u\x005\x007\x00f\x00a\x00\\\x00u\x005\x009\x00c\x00b\x00\\\x00u\x006\x00d\x00d\x00c\x00)\x00 \x00\\\x00u\x007\x00d\x000\x000\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x00e\x005\x00\\\x00u\x005\x00e\x00f\x00f\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x000\x000\x00\\\x00n\x00l\x00l\x00.\x00l\x00I\x00\\\x00u\x005\x00c\x006\x002\x00\\\x00u\x003\x000\x000\x00d\x00o\x00 \x00\\\x00u\x008\x002\x000\x00a\x00\\\x00u\x008\x00b\x005\x00c\x00\\\x00u\x008\x00a\x00a\x004\x00\\\x00u\x005\x007\x002\x008\x00\\\x00u\x005\x001\x006\x00c\x00\\\x00u\x005\x003\x00c\x00b\x00\\\x00u\x009\x006\x00c\x001\x00\\\x00u\x008\x000\x000\x005\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x004\x00b\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x000\x00a\x00.\x00\\\x00u\x005\x005\x005\x00e\x00\\\x00u\x009\x005\x00c\x006\x00\\\x00u\x008\x003\x007\x00b\x00\\\x00u\x003\x000\x001\x00d\x00\'\x00.\x00\\\x00n\x00\\\x00u\x005\x003\x00c\x00b\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x000\x000\x00\\\x00u\x005\x001\x006\x00c\x00\\\x00u\x006\x006\x002\x00f\x00\\\x00u\x005\x003\x004\x001\x00\\\x00u\x003\x000\x000\x00f\x00^\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x001\x006\x00\\\x00u\x003\x000\x001\x00d\x00 \x00\\\x00u\x007\x00a\x003\x00d\x00\\\x00u\x007\x00a\x007\x004\x00\\\x00u\x003\x000\x000\x00f\x00\\\x00u\x005\x003\x00c\x00b\x00\\\x00u\x008\x006\x009\x005\x00\\\x00u\x007\x005\x001\x00f\x00\\\x00u\x006\x005\x00b\x00c\x00\\\x00u\x006\x006\x000\x00e\x00\\\x00u\x005\x006\x000\x009\x00\\\x00u\x005\x00d\x001\x00d\x00\\\x00u\x007\x005\x003\x002\x00\\\x00u\x008\x00f\x00b\x000\x00\\\x00n\x00\\\x00u\x005\x003\x007\x003\x00\\\x00u\x002\x000\x001\x004\x00\\\x00u\x006\x002\x005\x002\x00\\\x00u\x003\x000\x000\x00f\x00]\x00\\\x00u\x005\x001\x004\x000\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x000\x000\x00 \x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x009\x004\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x009\x004\x00\\\x00u\x005\x009\x008\x002\x00\\\x00u\x005\x006\x00d\x00b\x00\\\x00u\x005\x00e\x007\x004\x00\\\x00u\x002\x000\x003\x005\x00 \x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x000\x000\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x001\x006\x00\\\x00u\x007\x009\x00d\x00f\x00 \x00\\\x00u\x007\x001\x00c\x003\x00\\\x00u\x007\x006\x00b\x00f\x00\\\x00u\x005\x001\x006\x00c\x00\\\x00u\x005\x00c\x004\x005\x00\\\x00u\x009\x000\x001\x005\x00\\\x00u\x005\x003\x00e\x003\x00\\\x00u\x003\x000\x000\x00f\x00\\\x00u\x002\x000\x003\x002\x00\\\x00n\x00\\\x00u\x006\x006\x002\x00f\x00\'\x00\\\x00u\x005\x001\x006\x00c\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x000\x000\x00\\\x00u\x005\x001\x004\x000\x00\\\x00u\x003\x000\x000\x00c\x00\\\x00u\x005\x001\x006\x00b\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x000\x003\x00\\\x00u\x007\x00a\x007\x004\x00\\\x00u\x005\x00e\x007\x004\x00\\\x00u\x002\x000\x003\x005\x00 \x00\\\x00u\x005\x001\x007\x006\x00\\\x00u\x006\x00f\x009\x007\x00\\\x00u\x008\x004\x000\x00b\x00\\\x00u\x008\x00d\x00d\x00d\x00\\\x00u\x006\x007\x000\x009\x00\\\x00u\x005\x00c\x007\x001\x00\\\x00u\x003\x000\x000\x008\x00\\\x00u\x007\x006\x007\x00e\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x000\x003\x00\\\x00u\x005\x003\x004\x001\x00\\\x00u\x003\x000\x000\x00f\x00^\x00\\\x00u\x005\x00e\x007\x004\x00\\\x00n\x00\\\x00n\x00\\\x00u\x009\x006\x006\x001\x00\\\x00u\x008\x000\x007\x006\x00\\\x00u\x007\x00e\x006\x00d\x00\\\x00u\x005\x003\x006\x00f\x00\\\x00u\x007\x00f\x003\x008\x00\\\x00u\x008\x001\x00d\x00f\x00\\\x00u\x006\x006\x00f\x009\x00[\x00\\\x00u\x005\x006\x00c\x00a\x00 \x00\\\x00u\x006\x00b\x006\x002\x00\\\x00u\x005\x005\x008\x00b\x00 \x00.\x00\\\x00u\x005\x00b\x00e\x00c\x00\\\x00u\x008\x002\x00a\x001\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x000\x000\x00\\\x00u\x005\x001\x004\x000\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x000\x000\x00 \x00\\\x00u\x005\x001\x004\x009\x00\\\x00u\x005\x001\x009\x007\x00 \x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x000\x000\x00_\x00\\\x00u\x004\x00e\x000\x000\x00\\\x00u\x003\x000\x000\x00d\x00\'\x00\\\x00u\x006\x006\x00c\x004\x00_\x00_\x00\\\x00n\x00\\\x00n\x00\'\x00 \x00 \x00\\\x00n\x00\\\x00n\x00 \x00 \x00 \x00\\\x00n\x00\\\x00n\x00 \x00 \x00\\\x00n\x00\\\x00n\x00 \x00\\\x00n\x00\\\x00n\x00 \x00 \x00 \x00\\\x00n\x00\\\x00n\x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00\\\x00n\x00\\\x00n\x00"\x00\r\x00\n\x00'
```

File text when opened as 'unicode' with MS Word:

```
"WantedCropped/13.jpg"  " \n\n\u8611,-'\u6b64\u56db\u90e1\u54b8\u7009] \u90e1\u301d\"\u540c\u6a39\u4e4b\u541f[\u300f\u8d66\u301d\u9023\u4ed9\u301d\u5982\u4e94\u5dbd\u301dZ\u87f2\n\u7e3d\u8f1d\u2026\u57c3 \u54ea\u6c9b\u570b\u6a39\u4e5f- \u5c71\u55da\u3015\u5011\u7fa9\u4e18\u8734\u301d\u7d2b\u967d\u9cf3\u967d\u76ce\n\u679d\u4e5f' \u8861\u5c71\u6cf0\u5c71\u5cb1\u5c71\u4e5fo\u59d4\u7be4\u73ca\u767d\u4fd7\u56e0\u2035 \u672c\u8e2b\u9806!\u301d\n\u4e00\u62b5\u4ee5\u4e00 \u90e1\u540d\u800c\u5c0a\u300f\u51a0\u3015\uff0c\u301d \u592b[\u8fe5\u53ca\u7837\u6d32\u54afl\u8655\u5b24\u55b5I\u594f\n\u88d4\u5011\u5f7c\u6b64\u856a\u6c6a\u4e00\u9683o4[\u59d1\u8056\u53ed}]\u4e94\u4ef0\u6094\u8010\u5b58\u8718\u5df2\u5410\u742a\u301d \u8cb4\n\u5929\u6daf\u82e5\u5317\u9130 \u301d\u2032 \u806f\u76e7\u5425\u4ee5\u300e\u5343\u8f09\u91cd\u6b61\u53d6\u787c\u300d\u5beb\u51fa\u5b50\u301d\u4ec3 \u300e\n\u4e4b\u9996) \u82f4\u3008\u579a\u601d\u65bc\u6b64\u8033@\n\u4ec1 \u5341] \u672c\u8e2b\u5cab\u7fa4\u5c41\u3008\u5c7e}\u5471\u300f\u529b\u2035 \u56b4\u301d'\u808b\u9ebb\u53ed\u52d8\u5c7el\u652f\u6d41\u5589\u5dfe\u6e05_I\u5fd6\u4e16\u9f3b\n{ \u6b21\u61f8\u6b8a\u986f\u898b\u820a\u672c\u6709\u6b5f. \u5f81\u5c7e\u9baa\u4ee5\u66f4) \u4f8b\u5982'\u6263_\u300el\u5c7e\n\u8373\u6597!\u95a9\u4e4b\u91d1\u91f5\u6eaa\u8e2b\u558e\u3001 \u6144\u6c9b\u570b \u90e1\u6587\u8936\u4e15\u301e\u5023\u4e0b\u5341 \u5c7e\n\n \n\n \n\n \n\n \u3011  \u3010I\u02cb \u3010\u3011\u8514lI_I(\u2035\u2032l|\u5fd6|\u9480|\u02cb| \u02cb \u02cb \u3009_\u3011IL \u301dl\n\n   \n\n\u301d \u54bd,\u4e16\u63c0\u4f8d\u76bf^\u52a0\u301e\u5274]\u9577\u4e88\u66f0\u5922\u91d1\u61f7 \u7738\u54ea\u2032\u535a\u6176) .\u8a5b\u5c7e'\u620c\u2026\n\u6750\u4e15\u6d3e\u4e0b\u5341\u4e16\u5b6b\u5141\u77f3\u5200\u300f\u61e6\u5beb\u4e88\u3001 \u4e88_.\u8db4\u66f4\n\u6b63o\n\n\u4e00\u3011 \u84bc\u752b\u6731\u8655\u6d3e\u2035 \u4fc2\u53cb\u5c7e\u9788\u5fea\u6d3e\u4e0b\u5eff\u56db\u4e16\u5b6b\u516c\u53cb\n\u4e15\u59cb\u9077) \u5176\u7646\u77b3\u9122\u5eb8{\u7236) \u7acb\u4ee5\u2032\u516c\u53cb\u4e00\u516c\n\u4e0b\u4e94\u4e16\u84c0\u2035 \u5747\u6c42\u4e15\u7009\u8087\u57fa\u59cb\u6ddc) \u7d00\u4ee5\u5eff\u4e00\nll.lI\u5c62\u300do \u820a\u8b5c\u8aa4\u5728\u516c\u53cb\u96c1\u8005\u4e4b\u4e0a.\u555e\u95c6\u837b\u301d'.\n\u53cb\u4e00\u516c\u662f\u5341\u300f^\u4e16\u301d \u7a3d\u7a74\u300f\u53cb\u8695\u751f\u65bc\u660e\u5609\u5d1d\u7532\u8fb0\n\u5373\u2014\u6252\u300f]\u5140\u4e00 \u4e94\u4e94\u5982\u56db\u5e74\u2035 \u4e00\u4e16\u79df \u71c3\u76bf\u516c\u5c45\u9015\u53e3\u300f\u2032\n\u662f'\u516c\u4e00\u5140\u300c\u516b\u4e03\u7a74\u5e74\u2035 \u5176\u6f97\u840b\u8ddd\u6709\u5c71\u3008\u767e\u4e03\u5341\u300f^\u5e74\n\n\u9661\u8076\u7e6d\u536f\u7f38\u81df\u66f9[\u56ca \u6b62\u558b .\u5bec\u82a1\u4e00\u5140\u4e00 \u5149\u5197 \u4e00_\u4e00\u300d'\u66c4__\n\n'  \n\n   \n\n  \n\n \n\n   \n\n    \n\n"
```

Comment: Your data looks like ordinary UTF-16, and decodes as such. What parts are UTF-8 in there?

Comment: So it is - the utf-16 was writing strings with \uXXXX, which have to be decoded again. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't look like a mix at all, it looks like pure UTF-16. But it does contain a bunch of `\n` and `\uXXXX` strings once it's decoded. Presumably you want to convert all of those to characters.

```
>>> print x.decode('utf-16').decode('unicode_escape')
"WantedCropped/13.jpg"  " 

蘑,-'此四郡咸瀉] 郡〝"同樹之吟[』赦〝連仙〝如五嶽〝Z蟲
```

Once you've converted the string to Unicode it's easy to convert to UTF-8:

```
>>> y = x.decode('utf-16').decode('unicode_escape')
>>> z = y.encode('utf-8')
```