# Python 3 - Decoding bytes that contains a mix of hex and unicode

Tags: python, python-3.x, arduino, type-conversion, pyserial

I'm porting [a codebase for the *Lasersaur* laser cutter](https://github.com/nortd/driveboardapp) from Python2 to Python3, and I'm having a bit of trouble decoding the serial data coming in from the onboard Arduino. The data comes in as a byte stream that mixes hex and unicode data, like so:

```
bytes: b'AC\xfb\xff\xff\xbfx\x85\x80\x80\xc0y\x80\x80\x80\xc0z'
data:  A C 251 255 255 x 133 128 128 y 128 128 128 z
```

Python2 was able to steamroll over the mixed-type data, and read in the serial data as a string of characters, after which `ord()` was used to determine if the character represented data or a status character. You can see how this is implemented in the original Python2 code starting at [line 367 here](https://github.com/nortd/driveboardapp/blob/master/backend/driveboard.py).

```
ord(data): 65 67 251 255 255 120 133 128 128 121 128 128 128 122
```

Python3 is more stringent about encodings, and throws me the following error when I try `bytes.decode('utf-8')`, because it gets to the first hex data `b'x\fb'` and chokes because it's a different format. Messing around with a few different codecs doesn't give any better results.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfb in position 2: invalid start byte
```

I found [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10009753/python-dealing-with-mixed-encoding-files) which addresses what I need pretty much exactly, but it seems that the error handling in Python 3 no longer works the same, and throws me this error when I try the solution there: `TypeError: 'UnicodeDecodeError' object is not subscriptable`.

I could modify the onboard code on the Arduino in order to get a saner serial encoding, but the main reason I'm porting to Python3 is that I can't get the right (read: old) Python2 libraries in order to execute the code and I don't want to run into the scenario where I inadvertently get to a state where it's impossible to communicate with the onboard arduino.

What I'd like to do is mimic the original functionality as closely as possible, and get out either a string of characters that I can call `ord()` on, or a mix of characters and numbers in a list. I'm a bit lost on how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have 'mixed' data, you have a bytes object. When you print it, Python represents all bytes whose value corresponds to a letter in ASCII as a letter, in order to help us identify text among it.

You can access any individual byte as an integer by indexing:

```
data = b'AC\xfb\xff\xff\xbfx\x85\x80\x80\xc0y\x80\x80\x80\xc0z'

print(data[0])
# 65
```

The value gets returned as an integer. (here, 65, which corresponds to 'A' in ASCII, hence its representation in the bytes string.)

So, a simple way to convert the bytes to a list of integers would be:

```
data_as_int = [b for b in data]
```

or even simpler:

```
data_as_int = list(data)
```

which gives us:

```
print(data_as_int)
# [65, 67, 251, 255, 255, 191, 120, 133, 128, 128, 192, 121, 128, 128, 128, 192, 122]
```

---

About your idea of converting the bytes to a string, in order to use `ord` afterwards: you can do it, but you have to use an encoding like `latin1` in which each byte corresponds to one character - which is not the case with `utf8`.
So, you could have done something like:

```
data_as_int = [ord(c) for c in data.decode('latin1')]
```

but this is less direct than the above solution.

Comment: Thank you! The print representation of the bytes object was confusing me a bit (why did the leading AC resolve as characters but not xyz later on?), and I assumed that indexing into it wouldn’t work nicely. Your explanation clears that up for me, and I think I should be able to work with it from here. Appreciate it!